# Android java app, replacing image on touch

Tags: java, android

I just want to say I am very new to java app development.

So I have this image floating around the screen and when I touch the screen I want the image to change colors (switch from image to image1)
I got this working but the image gets moved to starting point, I want the transition to be smooth and to take place where the image is at certain point.

I have this code in my GameView.java class

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private MainThread thread;
private CharacterSprite characterSprite;
private int col = 0;

public GameView(Context context){
    super(context);

    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(),this);
    setFocusable(true);
}



@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
characterSprite = new CharacterSprite(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.avdgreen), 100, 100);
thread.setRunning(true);
thread.start();

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){
    boolean retry = true;
    while(retry){
        try{
            thread.setRunning(false);
            thread.join();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        retry = false;
    }
}

public void update(){
    characterSprite.update();


}
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    int X = (int) event.getX();
    int Y = (int) event.getY();
    int eventaction = event.getAction();

    switch (eventaction) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if(col == 0){
                int ox = characterSprite.getX();
                int oy = characterSprite.getY();
                characterSprite.setX(ox);
                characterSprite.setX(oy);
                characterSprite = new CharacterSprite(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.avdgreen1), ox, oy);

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ACTION_UP "+"X: "+ox+" Y: "+oy, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                col = 1;
            }else{
                int ox = characterSprite.getX();
                int oy = characterSprite.getY();
                characterSprite.setX(ox);
                characterSprite.setX(oy);
                characterSprite = new CharacterSprite(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.avdgreen), ox, oy);

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ACTION_UP "+"X: "+ox+" Y: "+oy, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                col = 0;
            }


            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            break;
    }
    return true;
}
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas){
    super.draw(canvas);
    if(canvas!=null){
        characterSprite.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

This is where most of work is taking place, I also have CharacterSprite.java class which basicly creates the 'image' and makes it float around the screen:

```
public class CharacterSprite {
private Bitmap image;
private int x,y;
private int xVelocity = 10;
private int yVelocity = 5;
private int screenWidth = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
private int screenHeight = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;


public CharacterSprite(Bitmap bmp, int x, int y){

    image = bmp;

}


public int getX(){
    return x;
}

public int getY(){
    return y;
}

public void setX(int nx){
    x = nx;
}

public void setY(int ny){
    y = ny;
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.drawBitmap(image,x,y,null);
}

public void update(){

    if(x < 0 && y < 0){
        x = screenWidth / 2;
        y = screenHeight / 2;
    }else{
    x += xVelocity;
    y += yVelocity;
    if((x > screenWidth - image.getWidth()) || (x < 0)){
        xVelocity = xVelocity*-1;
    }
    if((y > screenHeight - image.getHeight()) || (y < 0)){
        yVelocity = yVelocity*-1;
    }
 }

}
```

as You can see I tried to get current x and y and set it back when creating new character, but that did not work, my guess is that this is happening because for a second the image is not on the screen and the whole thing reset but 1. I am not sure if thats right 2. I have no idea how I could fix that.
If anyone could point me where I should search that would be awesome.

@edit:
I changed to this `Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ACTION_UP "+"X: "+characterSprite.getX()+" Y: "+characterSprite.getY(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`
To debug and the output I am getting is `ACTION_UP X: 0 Y: 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER**

Added

```
public void updateD(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawBitmap(image,x,y,null);
}
```

To `CharacterSprite.java` and changed:

```
 if(col == 0){
                int ox =  550; //characterSprite.getX();
                int oy =  550;//characterSprite.getY();
               // characterSprite.setX(ox);
                //characterSprite.setX(oy);

                characterSprite = new CharacterSprite(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.avdgreen1));

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ACTION_UP "+"X: "+characterSprite.getX()+" Y: "+characterSprite.getY(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                col = 1;
            }
```

To:

```
      if(col == 0){
                characterSprite.setImg(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.avdgreen1));
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ACTION_UP "+"X: "+characterSprite.getX()+" Y: "+characterSprite.getY(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                col = 1;
            }
```

Comment: Is that an answer?

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท yes, my bad forgot to add it in the first line.